# OpenMP sections and single

Tags: c++, openmp

Hi :) I've a problem with this code. On Linux is working fine but on Visual Studio:

variables a,b,c are being used without being initialized.

```
//#include "pch.h"
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun1(int a) { return a * a; };
int fun2(int a) { return a + a; };
int fun3(int a) { return a + a + a; };
void printFun(int a, int b, int c) { cout << "\na: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c; };

int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int a, b, c;
        #pragma omp sections
        {
            #pragma omp section
            a = fun1(3);
            #pragma omp section
            b = fun2(2);
            #pragma omp section
            c = fun3(4);
        }

        #pragma omp single //master
        printFun(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

When i change 'single' to 'master', everything works, 
but i don't understand why i can't use 'single' like when i use 'for' instead of 'sections'.

Thanks for your help

sfmbe

Comment: Please try to provide a complete example that one can compile. Do post my reply, I had to fix a few things before I was able to compile & run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code should not work at all, the MSVC compiler is actually doing the "right thing".

The problem is that the code declares a,b,c as thread-private variables.  When each of the threads executes one section of the `sections` construct, it initializes it's own variable:

thread 0: a initialized, b & c not initialized
thread 1: a not ititalized, b initialized, c not initialized
thread 2: a & b not initialized, c initialized

When the code reaches the `single` construct, an arbitrary thread is chosen to execute the construct, so depending on which of the four threads is selected, you'll see a different result.

This code would work as you would expect it, as now a,b,c are shared variables and thus all threads see an initialized variable:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fun1(int a) { return a * a; };
int fun2(int a) { return a + a; };
int fun3(int a) { return a + a + a; };
void printFun(int a, int b, int c) { cout << "\na: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c; };

int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    int a, b, c;
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp sections
        {
            #pragma omp section
            a = fun1(3);
            #pragma omp section
            b = fun2(2);
            #pragma omp section
            c = fun3(4);
        }

        #pragma omp single
        printFun(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying ;) Yes, You're right, I understand it but unfortunately i must try to do this in single parallel. Maybe it's a mistake in my exercise (i think so). I thought omp barrier (but sections do this at end of function) will help, but of course these are private variables.

Comment: Your initial code was simply put doing something unexpected. The code I showed you still uses a parallel and a single construct.